# Is there any ordinary reason to use open() instead of fopen()?

Tags: c, file, posix, libc

I'm doing a small project in C after quite a long time away from it. These happen to include some file handling. I noticed in various documentation that there are functions which return `FILE *` handles and others which return (small integer) descriptors. Both sets of functions offer the same basic services I need so it really does not matter I use.

But I'm curious about the collection wisdom: is it better to use `fopen()` and friends, or `open()` and friends?

**Edit** Since someone mentioned buffered vs unbuffered and accessing devices, I should add that one part of this small project will be writing a userspace filesystem driver under FUSE. So the file level access could as easily be on a device (e.g. a CDROM or a SCSI drive) as on a "file" (i.e. an image).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The objection that "fopen" is portable and "open" isn't is bogus.

fopen is part of libc, open is a POSIX system call.

Each is as portable as the place they come from.

i/o to fopen'ed files is (you must assume it may be, and for practical purposes, it is) buffered by libc, file descriptors open()'ed are not buffered by libc (they may well be, and usually are buffered in the filesystem -- but not everything you open() is a file on a filesystem.

What's the point of fopen'ing, for example, a device node like /dev/sg0, say, or /dev/tty0...  What are you going to do?  You're going to do an ioctl on a FILE *?  Good luck with that.

Maybe you want to open with some flags like O_DIRECT -- makes no sense with fopen().

Answer (score 16):

It is better to use open() if you are sticking to unix-like systems and you might like to:

- Have more fine-grained control over unix permission bits on file creation.
- Use the lower-level functions such as read/write/mmap as opposed to the C buffered stream I/O functions.
- Use file descriptor (fd) based IO scheduling (poll, select, etc.) You can of course obtain an fd from a FILE * using fileno(), but care must be taken not to mix FILE * based stream functions with fd based functions.
- Open any special device (not a regular file)

It is better to use fopen/fread/fwrite for maximum portability, as these are standard C functions, the functions I've mentioned above aren't.

Comment: I'm glad we have someone spelling out the benefits of using open() every once in a while.

Answer (score 4):

fopen works at a higher level than open ....
fopen returns you a pointer to FILE stream which is similar to the stream abstraction that you read in C++

open returns you a file descriptor for the file opened ... It does not provide you a stream abstraction and you are responsible for handling the bits and bytes yourself ... This is at a lower level as compared to fopen

Stdio streams are buffered, while open() file descriptors are not. Depends on what you need. You can also create one from the other:

int fileno (FILE * stream) returns the file descriptor for a FILE *, FILE * fdopen(int fildes, const char * mode) creates a FILE * from a file descriptor.

Be careful when intermixing buffered and non-buffered IO, since you'll lose what's in your buffer when you don't flush it with fflush().

Answer (score 3):

Yes. When you need a low-level handle.

On UNIX operating systems, you can generally exchange file handles and sockets.

Also, low-level handles make for better ABI compatibility than FILE pointers.

Comment: int fd = fileno(file); /* gets a low level handle from a FILE * */

Comment: NOTE: fileno is posix and not c89/c99 though.

Comment: @Joshua: are you referring to the ability to pass file descriptors between processes (esoteric, but I know of software where it is done), or changing between file pointers and file descriptors, or something else?  Remember, fdopen() can convert a file descriptor into a file pointer.

Comment: On the other hand, if you need a file descriptor, you're already outside the realm of standard C, so needing fileno is no problem.

Comment: Jonathan, no. Sometimes different compilers have a different idea about FILE and FILE *, but the low-level handle is defined by the OS ABI so your .o file is more likely to work with the .o file from some other compiler.

Answer (score 3):

*read()*  & *write()*   use unbuffered I/O. (***fd***: integer file descriptor)

*fread()* & *fwrite()*  use buffered I/O. (***FILE**** structure pointer)

Binary data written to a pipe with *write()* ***may not*** be able to read binary data with *fread()*, because of byte alignments, variable sizes, etc. Its a crap-shoot.

Most low-level device driver code uses unbuffered I/O calls.

Most application level I/O uses buffered.

Use of the *FILE**  and its associated functions
is OK on a machine-by-machine basis: but portability is lost
on other architectures in the reading and writing of binary data.
fwrite() is buffered I/O and can lead to unreliable results if
written for a 64 bit architecture and run on a 32bit; or (Windows/Linux).
Most OSs have compatibility macros within their own code to prevent this.

For low-level binary I/O portability *read()* and *write()* guarantee
the same binary reads and writes when compiled on differing architectures.
The basic thing is to pick one way or the other and be consistent about it,
throughout the binary suite.

```
<stdio.h>  // mostly FILE*  some fd input/output parameters for compatibility
             // gives you a lot of helper functions -->
List of Functions
       Function      Description
       ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
       clearerr      check and reset stream status
       fclose        close a stream
       fdopen        stream open functions //( fd argument, returns FILE*)                      feof          check and reset stream status
       ferror        check and reset stream status
       fflush        flush a stream
       fgetc         get next character or word from input stream
       fgetpos       reposition a stream
       fgets         get a line from a stream
       fileno        get file descriptor   // (FILE* argument, returns fd) 
       fopen         stream open functions
       fprintf       formatted output conversion
       fpurge        flush a stream
       fputc         output a character or word to a stream
       fputs         output a line to a stream
       fread         binary stream input/output
       freopen       stream open functions
       fscanf        input format conversion
       fseek         reposition a stream
       fsetpos       reposition a stream
       ftell         reposition a stream
       fwrite        binary stream input/output
       getc          get next character or word from input stream
       getchar       get next character or word from input stream
       gets          get a line from a stream
       getw          get next character or word from input stream
       mktemp        make temporary filename (unique)
       perror        system error messages
       printf        formatted output conversion
       putc          output a character or word to a stream
       putchar       output a character or word to a stream
       puts          output a line to a stream
       putw          output a character or word to a stream
       remove        remove directory entry
       rewind        reposition a stream
       scanf         input format conversion
       setbuf        stream buffering operations
       setbuffer     stream buffering operations
       setlinebuf    stream buffering operations
       setvbuf       stream buffering operations
       sprintf       formatted output conversion
       sscanf        input format conversion
       strerror      system error messages
       sys_errlist   system error messages
       sys_nerr      system error messages
       tempnam       temporary file routines
       tmpfile       temporary file routines
       tmpnam        temporary file routines
       ungetc        un-get character from input stream
       vfprintf      formatted output conversion
       vfscanf       input format conversion
       vprintf       formatted output conversion
       vscanf        input format conversion
       vsprintf      formatted output conversion
       vsscanf       input format conversion
```

**So for basic use I would personally use the above without mixing idioms too much.**

By contrast,

```
<unistd.h>   write()
             lseek()
             close()
             pipe()
<sys/types.h>
<sys/stat.h>
<fcntl.h>  open()
           creat()
           fcntl() 
all use file descriptors.
```

These provide fine-grained control over reading and writing bytes 
(recommended for special devices and fifos (pipes) ).

So again, use what you need, but keep consistent in your idioms and interfaces.
If most of your code base uses one mode , use that too, unless there is 
a real reason not to. Both sets of I/O library functions are extremely reliable
and used millions of times a day.

*note--* If you are interfacing C I/O  with another language,
(perl, python, java, c#, lua ...) *check out* what the developers of those languages 
recommend before you write your C code and save yourself some trouble.

Comment: "but portability is lost on other architectures in the reading and writing of binary data. fwrite() is buffered I/O and can lead to unreliable results if written for a 64 bit architecture and run on a 32bit; or (Windows/Linux)." - this is completely untrue. all you need to do is make sure to open the file in BINARY mode

Answer (score 2):

usually, you should favor using the standard library (fopen). However, there are occasions where you will need to use open directly.

One example that comes to mind is to work around a bug in an older version of solaris which made fopen fail after 256 files were open. This was because they erroniously used an unsigned char for the fd field in their struct FILE implementation instead of an int. But this was a very specific case.

Comment: That 'older version of Solaris' includes Solaris 10 (current) - at least for 32-bit code.

Answer (score 0):

fopen and its cousins are buffered.  open, read, and write are not buffered.  Your application may or may not care.

fprintf and scanf have a richer API that allows you to read and write formatted text files.  read and write use fundamental arrays of bytes.  Conversions and formatting must be hand crafted.

The difference between file descriptors and (FILE *) is really inconsequential.

Randy