# C - storing user input in a dynamic char array?

Tags: c, file

I want to read some string input from the user and write it to a file. Right now I'm doing

```
char name[25];
scanf("%s", name);
int handle = open("./visitors.txt", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);
if (handle < 0){
   printf("File error.\n");
   return;
}
lseek(handle, -sizeof(name), SEEK_END);
write(handle, name, sizeof(name));
```

This, of course is not right, since most of the time the user doesn't write 25 characters, only less, so when the user inputs 5 characters, the other 20 will be empty, and I end up having 5 chars the user put in and 20 chars gibberish in my output file. How can I make sure only the user input is being written to the file?

Comment: By reading the manual of `scanf`? `%s` causes the output to be null-terminated.

Comment: `-sizeof(name)` should be `-(off_t)sizeof(name)`

Comment: @M.M Doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using raw system calls to handle the file operations. Unless your intention is specifically to learn about system calls, you should not do that. [The `write` call](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) writes a number of bytes specified by the third parameter. `sizeof(name)` is wrong in this case. It will **not** return the length of the string, it will return the length of the entire buffer.

The standard [`strlen` function](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strlen.htm) gives you the string length. So running `strlen(name)` will give you 5 if the user enters 5 characters, unlike the `sizeof` you are using.

Unless you want to learn about system calls specifically, you should probably handle file operations with the C standard library, using `fprintf` to output to file, and functions such as `fopen` and `fclose`. Take a look [at the fprintf docs](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fprintf.htm) that also link to the other functions.

Comment: That was it! Using `strlen()` instead of `sizeof()` fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the reason you want to use low level system calls `open`, `lseek`, `write`. Usually it's a lot more convenient to use standard C `fopen`, `fscanf`, `fprintf` functions for such tasks.

In this case, you may try `fgets` to get string input from `stdin`, then use `fprintf` with `%s` to write to file. You can still use buffer `name[25]` or `name[100]` (envision for largest input from `stdin`). Just initialise it properly to make sure it's NULL terminated. Then `fprintf` with `%s` would write the string properly (ie without gibberish ending) to file.

Comment: How do I make sure the buffer is null terminated?

Comment: Just initialise it `char name[25] = "";`

Comment: If you need to use `name` in a loop, then `memset` it to all zero at the beginning of the loop

Comment: *I'm not sure the reason you want to use low level system calls `open`, `lseek`, `write`.*  Performance? Control? Flexibility? Reduced dependencies?  Learning?

Comment: @artm Try doing lock-free atomic reads/writes from random file offsets with `fread()`/`fwrite()`

Comment: @AndrewHenle I agree, some low level operations as you mentioned would require I/O system calls. I think for common user space problems like OP we don't really need that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544662/is-there-any-ordinary-reason-to-use-open-instead-of-fopen

Comment: @artm initialising it `char name[25] = ""` didn't do anything.